# Cast shadow on top of LinearLayout using android:elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have this `LinearLayout` that is going to be placed on the bottom of an activity layout. I want this `LinearLayout` to have a 4dp elevation, just like the top toolbar should have, however, since `android:elevation` places the shadow below the ui component and this specific component (linearLayout) is going to be on the bottom of the screen, I won't see any elevation at all..

This is my `LinearLayout` code, and an image of it with the default elevation implemented:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_toolbar_menu_selector"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_toolbar_menu_selector"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bookmarkButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_toolbar_menu_selector"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Is there a way, using `elevation` to place a shadow on top of the ui component?**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there isn't. you should use a drawable.

Comment: (dirty hack: have you tried setting a huge number, like elevation=40dp ? Maybe elevation casts a little shadow to the top also, and that may became visible with large values)

Comment: I'm using a drawable for pre v21, but I was in hope that I didn't need that for v21.. However, I really really loved that little hack, I set the elevation to 30 dp and it works, it's very subtle, but I like it! Thanks a lot @mvai

Comment: Glad it worked, I'm going to post an asnwer then.

Comment: do it :), I'll be glad to accept it @mvai

Comment: May I ask how you achieved that gloss effect? I don't know how to call it, but the linear layout has a brighter color to the left, I think you know what I mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't theoretically do it with `android:elevation`, in the sense that you can't choose the direction where the shadow is going to be cast.

There are two solutions.

**1. Drawables**

You could, for instance, put an `ImageView` right above your layout and set `android:src="@drawable/shadow"`. This should be a vertical `GradientDrawable` defined in XML, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

**2. Workaround**

While most of the shadow is actually below the view, a subtle shadow is also above. A workaround might be using a very high value for `elevation`, like `40dp`: the bottom part is going to be hidden due to your layout, while the top is going to be expanded and look like a common shadow.

In either case, you do not have control over the elevation value in `dp`, in the sense that you can't be sure your shadow is equivalent to the one cast by `android:elevation=4dp`.

Comment: Also the workaround solution works perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the workaround solution is great for higher end devices. For lower end devices on something like jelly bean, elevation causes the view group to really elevate (based on how much elevation value you set), with the shadow that it generated to push the view group inwards (shadow seem to always be completely visible). At least this is my observation.

Answer (score 2):

use like as;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="205dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        // CHILD VIEWS
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Negative margins are not officially supported.

Comment: Negative margins are officially supported.

Comment: Supported margins are officially negative.

Comment: Negative support is marginally official.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code above of view in which you want top elevation or add `android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"` and add below of above view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.01dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollbar"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_4" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this i am unable to set background through xml then i tried the programmatic way to solve that and i work perfectly refer this if facing  problem on show shadow in Linear Layout

```
lprofile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_with_shadow);
```

lprofile is my ref of Linear layout and background_with_shadow is xml for applying shadow i hope i will for ur requirmement...thank u..

Comment: What/Where is `R.drawable.background_with_shadow`?