# Set elevation to top of tablayout

Tags: android, xml

I used default elevation attribute in xml but the shadow appears bottom of layout, so i want to display the shadow to the top of tablayout like this [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397225/8089770

Comment: oops , duplicate post can i delete this post ?

Comment: No issues just edit the question with links you have visited.. solution you have tried and errors.. it will be perfect question.. and if it's solved then delete it