# Shadow at the top of Bottom App Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, mdc-components

I am using the new [Bottom App Bar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/) from the Material Design Components. I am trying to give shadow at the top of the Bottom App Bar like the one in Google Tasks app as shown below.

[image]

I have tried using both `android:elevation` and `app:elevation` attribute. Please help.

Comment: Here is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397225/4255978

Comment: showing shadow on the top breaks the material guidelines. You can not have shadow in both positive and negative Y direction. (The shadow direction for "Add a new task" button and action button are in opposite direction). You should avoid it.

Comment: @RahulKumar This screenshot shown in the question is of the Tasks app by Google.

Comment: @Mehul they are known for breaking their own guidelines. So what can I say.

Comment: @RahulKumar But if you are going to use Bottom App Bar having white color as background then you will have to add shadow as it won't be recognizable. I tried doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650778/android-bottom-navigation-bar-with-drop-shadow).

---

**Step 1**
Create a `shape_drawable.xml` file in the drawable folder as shown below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#1F000000"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:angle="90" />    
</shape>
```

---

**Step 2**
Create a `View`, set the `shape_drawable.xml` as its background and then place the view just above the BottomAppBar.

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="4dp"
android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
android:background="@drawable/shape_drawable"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Elevation has been fixed in the Android material components 1.1.0 (alpha) release according to [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/560c9822844608da6ea16c0c4815eb437d819fc1) commit.

**Edit**

for those wondering, this is how you add the new dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    // ...
}
```

More information about getting started can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and info about releases can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases).

Cheers!